# Removing words from file if exists in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have 2 files of strings.

Some of the strings in both files are the same.

I want to remove those strings and write it to a new file.

This is my source code:

```
file = open ("fileC.txt", "w")

with open('fileA.txt') as a, open('fileB.txt') as b:
    a_words = set(a.read().split())
    b_words = set(b.read().split())
    both_words = ('\n'.join(a_words & b_words))
    c_words = a_words.replace(both_words, "")
    print (c_words)
    file.write(c_words + "\n)

file.close()
```

This produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I also tried lists, rather than sets:

```
a_words = a.read().split()
b_words = b.read().split()
c_words = a_words.replace(b_words, "")
```

Which produces this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Try `a_words=list(a_words)`. Lists don't have a replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = open ("fileC.txt", "w")
with open('fileA.txt') as a, open('fileB.txt') as b:
    b=b.read().split()
    r='\n'.join([e for e in a.read().split() if e not in b])
    file.write(r)
```

Try this